# How to generate Google Translate API key

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-authentication, api-key

I am attempting to hire a developer to program a Google Translate API call into salesforce.  I need to provide him with an API key for Google Translate on our Google Cloud account but can't figure out how to generate that key.  Here is a slightly outdated definition of the integration I want to ask him to build.
http://adaptatechnologies.com/implementing-google-translation-services-salesforce/
Where can I find the specific instructions to generate the Google Translate API key?

Comment: In order to help the community in the future, could you please accept or upvote one of the answers? just as a kind reminder take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

API keys are the same for all GCP APIs. Instructions here: 
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys

Answer (score 0):

The **API keys** can be created directly from the [APIs & Services](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) section of the GCP console, you can use the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#creating_an_api_key) that contains the step-by-step process, as mentioned by [Rob Kochman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6934031/rob-kochman).

Additionally, I would recommend you to [set some restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions) to the in order to define the specific services that can be used with each key (**Translation API in this case**), as well as determine the web sites, IP addresses, or apps can use an API key; in this way, you can add some additional security to your key avoiding to publicly exposing it which cloud lead to the compromise of your account and the generation of unexpected charges.